# Login loop after update to 17.04 Have to do -reinstall ubuntu-desktop and dpkg-reconfigure lightdm every boot up

Tags: xorg, login, lightdm, 17.04

After update to 17.04 from 16.10 i have problem with login loop.I was searching forums but nothing helps.

I've tried `sudo chown username:username .Xauthority`, `sudo chmod a+wt /tmp` with no luck, also reinstalled nvidia drivers. Nothing helps

Checked `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`, and `~/.xserver-errors` - no errors

I have to do `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` and
 `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` every time system boot up and then when i do `sudo reboot` Im able to login without loop error. How to fix this permanently. Please help

Comment: It is always better to do a clean install than update,  you can take backup of your files and do a clean install.   The problem you are describing is something related to lightdm or Nvidia drivers.

Comment: What was the solution to your problem?